# For every $x \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$, $\sin(x)+\cos(x)\geq 1$. Prove rigorously by contradiction.

Tags: proof-writing

For every $x \in [o,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $\sin(x)+\cos(x)\geq 1$.
How do you prove this rigorously by contradiction?

I understand you start by assuming that $\sin(x)+ \cos(x)<1$ and prove this is a false statement. I can see from drawing the graphs this is false but how do I show it algebraically?

Comment: This isn't true...  For $x = \frac{2\pi}{3}$, $\sin{x} + \cos{x} < 1$.

Comment: sorry I wrote down the wrong interval

Comment: You are 7 hours late lol.  Maybe you should repost this as a new question with the correct interval.

Answer (score 2):

Both $\cos(x)$ and $-\sin(x)$ are convex functions on the interval $(\pi/2,\pi)$. Since in the endpoints of such interval se have $\cos(x)-\sin(x)=-1$, it follows that $\cos(x)-\sin(x)\leq -1$ all over $[\pi/2,\pi]$. The last inequality implies that $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ is a decreasing function over $[\pi/2,\pi]$, so, for any $x\in(\pi/2,\pi]$,
$$\sin(x)+\cos(x)<\sin(\pi/2)+\cos(\pi/2)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You may need the formula:
$$
 \sin x \sin\frac\pi 4+\cos x\cos\frac\pi 4 = \cos\left(x - \frac \pi 4\right) $$

Comment: See the comment under the original question. What the OP is asking is not true.

Comment: @5xum: whether it is true or wrong,  it allows to have a clear idea  what the size of the sum is depending of the interval of $x$ considered.

Answer (score 0):

suqaring $\sin(x)+\cos(x)<1$ we obtain
$\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2+2\sin(x)\cos(x)<1$
since $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$ we get
$\sin(2x)<0$ which is true since $\frac{\pi}{2}\le x\le \pi$
you can also use that $\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  Why is this a contradiction?  $\sin{2x}$ *is* negative on $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$, isn't it?

Comment: Squaring isn't an order preserving function.

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot You're not doing anything wrong, in fact it's easy to find $x$ in the given interval such that $\sin(x)=-\cos(x)$, yielding $0\ge 1$.

Comment: @GitGud So is this answer wrong then?  The only contradiction I can see is if we specifically look at the value $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, since at that point, you get that the left hand side $=1$, so it is not $< 1$...

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot I was referring to the common in the question, but I'd say the answer is wrong because it's using $\forall a,b(a<b\implies a^2<b^2)$. I didn't read past this.

Comment: since $\sin(x)+\cos(x)\geq 1$ is not true if $\frac{\pi}{2}\le x\le \pi$

Comment: The only problem is that the proof is done backward:
π/2≤ x ≤ π => sin(2*x) ≤ 0 => $(sin(x)+cos(x))^2 = sin(2x) +sin(x)^2+cos(x)^2=1 +2*sin(2x) ≤ 1$ => |sin(x) +cos(x)| ≤ 1. 
  u ≤ |u| => sin(x) + cos(x) ≤ 1  when π/2≤ x ≤ π

Comment: thank you for your comment

Answer (score -1):

We start with the assumption $$\sin x+\cos x<1$$ and rearrange, $$\sin x<1-\cos x$$ square both sides $$\sin ^2 x<1-2\cos x+\cos^2x$$ and manipulate further. $$\sin^2x-\cos^2x<1-2\cos x$$ Since $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ and $\sin^2x+\cos^2x-2\cos^2x=\sin^2x-\cos^2x$, $$1-2\cos^2x<1-2\cos x$$ $$2\cos^2x>2\cos x$$ $$\cos x>1$$ which is false since the codomain of $\cos x$ is $-1\le x\le 1$.

Comment: The original statement, that is "$\cos x + \sin x \geq 1$ for $x\in [\pi/2, \pi]$", is true. Therefore, you made a mistake.

Comment: @5xum No, the original statement is *false*.

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot That was what I wanted to write. The original statement is false, and since this post "proves" it is true, it means it must be faulty.

Comment: @5xum Ooh, ok, sorry!

Comment: @5xum You're right, but I can't figure out what my error is. Can you point it out?

Comment: I wrote down the wrong interval so this seems correct now I have changed it